# Break an input string into a list using Arduino

Tags: list, split, arduino, read-eval-print-loop, arduino-uno

I am working on a very basic REPL for Arduino. To get parameters, I need to split a `String` into parts, separating using spaces. I do not know how I would store the result. For example, `pinmode 1 input` would result in a list: `"pinmode", 1, "input"`. The 1 would have to be an `int`. I have looked at other Stack Overflow answers, but they require a `char` input.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `String`.  That's the reason all the other answers use `char`, commonly called C strings (lower case "s").  `String` uses "dynamic memory" (i.e., the heap), which is bad on this small microcontroller.  It also add 1.6k to your program size.

The simplest thing to do is save each received character into a `char` array, until you get the newline character, '\n'.  Be sure to add the NUL character at the end, and be sure your array is sized appropriately.

Then process the array using the C string library: strcmp, strtoul, strtok, isdigit, etc.  Learning about these routines will really pay off, as it keeps your program small and fast.  C strings are easy to print out, as well.

Again, stay away from `String`.  It is tempting to beginners, because it is easy to understand.  However, it has many subtle, complicated and unpredictable ways to make your embedded program fail.  This is not a PC with lots of RAM and a swap file on a hard drive.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do that? I want to store the data from serial in a variable called `content`, and be able to compare the first word in the input with a phrase. If the phrases match, I want to do something.

Comment: Um, looked at the other Stack Overflow answers that require a char input?  What have you tried?  Edit your post above and insert your code, and be sure to use ^K to format a code section.  For a general plan of attack, could I suggest: (1) Start with a simple echo program.  (2) Save each char in an array until you get the newline and print it all. (3) Use strtok to split the array and print each piece. (4) Use strcmp and strtoul to parse each piece.